# Two CellValues with Different Styles in a cell in OPEN XML SDK 2.0

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk, cells

Im tasked to use OPEN XML SDK 2.0 and had encountered this problem. Is it possible to have  different styles for a single CellValue inside a cell something like the picture below:

[image]

A: The plain text

B: Bold and Underlined

NOTE: I need both in a single cell only thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that is possible.  One way is to format the value that will be inserted into the `SharedStringTable`.  This snippet will create your example above:

```
        // Creates an SharedStringItem instance and adds its children.
        public SharedStringItem GenerateSharedStringItem()
        {
            SharedStringItem sharedStringItem1 = new SharedStringItem();

            Run run1 = new Run();

            RunProperties runProperties1 = new RunProperties();
            Bold bold1 = new Bold();
            Underline underline1 = new Underline();
            FontSize fontSize1 = new FontSize(){ Val = 11D };
            Color color1 = new Color(){ Theme = (UInt32Value)1U };
            RunFont runFont1 = new RunFont(){ Val = "Calibri" };
            FontFamily fontFamily1 = new FontFamily(){ Val = 2 };
            FontScheme fontScheme1 = new FontScheme(){ Val = FontSchemeValues.Minor };

            runProperties1.Append(bold1);
            runProperties1.Append(underline1);
            runProperties1.Append(fontSize1);
            runProperties1.Append(color1);
            runProperties1.Append(runFont1);
            runProperties1.Append(fontFamily1);
            runProperties1.Append(fontScheme1);
            Text text1 = new Text();
            text1.Text = "Project Name:";

            run1.Append(runProperties1);
            run1.Append(text1);

            Run run2 = new Run();

            RunProperties runProperties2 = new RunProperties();
            FontSize fontSize2 = new FontSize(){ Val = 11D };
            Color color2 = new Color(){ Theme = (UInt32Value)1U };
            RunFont runFont2 = new RunFont(){ Val = "Calibri" };
            FontFamily fontFamily2 = new FontFamily(){ Val = 2 };
            FontScheme fontScheme2 = new FontScheme(){ Val = FontSchemeValues.Minor };

            runProperties2.Append(fontSize2);
            runProperties2.Append(color2);
            runProperties2.Append(runFont2);
            runProperties2.Append(fontFamily2);
            runProperties2.Append(fontScheme2);
            Text text2 = new Text(){ Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve };
            text2.Text = " ALLAN";

            run2.Append(runProperties2);
            run2.Append(text2);

            sharedStringItem1.Append(run1);
            sharedStringItem1.Append(run2);
            return sharedStringItem1;
        }
```

You can insert that into the `SharedStringTable` and then set the cell value to be the index in the `SharedStringTable` where this was inserted.

There might be some other references that I forgot to include that might be defined in the `StylesPart`.  I recommend creating this example in a blank Excel document and then using the [Open XML Productivity Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) to look at the XML.  The tool will also supply you with the code I provided you above.  It should give you a general direction on where to go next.